# Contact is locked by another operation

Tags: xdb

I'm having an issue identifying xDB contacts...  I'm trying to call the Identify() method in my controller action, but I see this error in the logs:

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message: A contact is locked by another operation.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the full stack trace.

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message: A contact is locked by another operation.
>   Source: Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbContactStorage.LoadContactIdentifier(ID contactId, LeaseOwner leaseOwner)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.SaveContactWithIdentifier(IContact contact, ContactSaveOptions saveOptions)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass9.b__7()
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.Try(Action action)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.SaveContact(IContact contact, ContactSaveOptions saveOptions)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.SaveContact(Contact contact, ContactSaveOptions options)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.SubmitContact(Contact contact, ContactSaveOptions options)

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the stack trace, please?

Comment: Updated original question with the full stack trace.

Comment: Is this a duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235368/sitecore-current-contact-is-locked-for-identification

Comment: certainly wasn't intended as a duplicate, but it's a common issue many Sitecore devs run in to.

Comment: I can't link as duplicate anyway, posted answer and source to original below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235368/sitecore-current-contact-is-locked-for-identification

### Why this happens

Normally, you will see this error when you forget to set `Analytics.ClusterName` in the configuration file `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config`. This becomes a problem because in the beginning of every session Sitecore lock the current contact by creating a `Lease` in xDB. It uses `Analytics.ClusterName` as the identifier of the lock.

The error you are seeing occurs because your Sitecore instance doesn't realize that it owns the lease on the contact since the lease owner identifier is missing.

If you look at your contact in the collection database, you are likely to see something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `Owner` document does not have the `Identifier` field set. This indicates that the entity that created the lease did not provide an identifier (its value was an empty string or `null`).

### Solution

To solve this in a development environment, just set both `Analytics.ClusterName` and `Analytics.HostName` setting values to the local domain name you're using when accessing the application, e.g. ``sitecore.

```
<setting name="Analytics.ClusterName" value="sitecore" />
<setting name="Analytics.HostName" value="sitecore" />
```

You can read more about these settings [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/xdb%20configuration/configure%20a%20content%20delivery%20server).

**UPDATE:** Sitecore has added a knowledge base article about this issue: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/965127

Comment: That's a nice answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Anicho's answer, if you correct the configuration any existing locked sessions will throw errors until the current lease expires. To speed this up, you can execute the following against your analytics database:

```
db.getCollection('Contacts').update(
    { "$and": [ 
        { "Lease.Owner.Type" :  {$eq:0} }, 
        { "Lease.Owner.Identifier" :  {$exists: false} } 
    ]},
    { $set: { "Lease" : null } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

This will drop any leases that were owned by a web cluster but don't have an identifier. Run this after you change the config (and before if you really want to minimise errors)